# GWT.create and wrap existing html element

Tags: gwt, gwtmockito

Is it possible to create a TextBox using `GWT.create`, not the constructor, and wrap an existing HTML element?
I tried:

```
TextBox text=GWT.create(TextBox.class)
text.setElement(DOM.createInput()) (2)
```

The above fails on line (2) with "cannot set element twice ..."

I need this in order to use GwtMockito and test a component that needs to create a TextBox.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know much about gwtmockito. So you can't use the constructor?

Comment: Can't you use dependency injection here? I know GIN calls GWT.create() on any element that you ask it for so just inject a `Provider<TextBox>` and call `provider.get()` ?

Comment: @Baz gwtmockito can only mock the calls to GWT.create(), it doesn't know to mock ctors

Comment: @slugmandrew I've updated my question, the code actually fails at (2) so even if I had a Provider<TextBox> it would only create the component but not also do setElement(...)

Comment: @Dan Can't you use `TextBox#wrap(Element)`?

Comment: @Baz TextBox#wrap(Element) uses TextBox textBox = new TextBox(element) internally so kind of the same - btw, about GwtMockito, it's quite nice as a framework and some people say they used it successfully instead of GWTTestCase - that's what I hope to achieve too without refactoring the code base too much

Comment: a nice blog about gwtmockito usage in real scenario: http://blog.codiform.com/2011/01/building-testable-applications-with.html

Answer (score 3):

UIObject have a package protected replaceElement Method which will do what you like to do.

Building a wrapper in the right package like this:

```
package com.google.gwt.user.client.ui;

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;

public class ElementReplace
{
    public static void replaceElement(UIObject obj, Element elem)
    {
        obj.replaceElement(elem);
    }
}
```

and it is possible to access the method.

Comment: Indeed, interesting workaround. However, I'd be concerned using this application-wide. `replaceElement` was made package private for a reason. As the javadocs say: "Replaces this object's browser element. **This method exists only to support a specific use-case in Image, and should not be used by other classes**." It might work now, but the GWT team could remove it in the future or change the implementation in a way that will break your application.

Comment: I agree with you, this is a dirty hack and is not relisable, but for a testing enviroment it should be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you'd have to resort to using some sort of factory:

```
public interface TextBoxFactory {
    TextBox wrap(Element element);
}
```

This will get injected into your view and you'll use the factory to wrap the existing element in a `TextBox`. The default implementation will, of course, just use [`TextBox#wrap(Element)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html#wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)), as suggested by Baz. For the purposes of your tests, you'll use an implementation that returns a Mockito mock.

Not the prettiest solution, but given the circumstances, I can't think of a "cleaner" one.